# CollectionView layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been working on this for a while and can't figure out how to get my cells to display correctly. There are many Stack Overflow questions on this but I can't seem to figure it out for my situation. I have a CollectionView on top of a UITableViewController (not inside of a table view cell). I'm trying to have my collection view cells display with 3 horizontal rows and I need it to adjust to the different iPhone & iPad screen sizes. I've attached two photos. One showing my storyboard view controller and one displaying the simulator of how it is appearing. The cells rows always have a large gap between them. I want it display like a grid (like iPhone photos app). Here is the following code for my UICollectionView:

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return _foursquarePhotoArray.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"photoCell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *wineryImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

Photo *photo = [_foursquarePhotoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [wineryImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photo.photoURLString] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Grapes"]];
});

return cell;

}

-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

int numberOfCellInRow = 5;
CGFloat cellWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width/numberOfCellInRow;

   return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (CGFloat) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0; // This is the minimum inter line spacing, can be more
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (not a custom layout), in your view controller you can adjust properties of the layout via the `collectionView` (something like `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout`), especially take a look at the `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` properties.

`minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` control different spaces with regard to the scrollDirection of your layout, so you might try setting both of them to 0, or just tweaking around both of them.

If you have a nib/storyboard for your collection view and don't use a custom layout, then you can tweak those values right in the Size Inspector:

Right here -> 
[image]

I'm not sure whether I understood that correctly, but do you have issues  with the sizing of the cells as well, or was it just side information ?

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried messing around with the different size inspector options but still not doing what I need. It looks good on the 5s but then when I do it on a bigger device the spaces get bigger. I appear to be having issues with just the side information. The cells keep their size.

Comment: What exactly happens on bigger devices ? Does the vertical spacing grow only ?

Comment: It grows horizontally(I have it scrolling horizontally). I want all the cells to have the same amount of spacing throughout and to adjust from different iPhone sizes and iPad sizes.

Comment: so your collectionview grows horizontally (there is always 3 rows, the images expand to the right ?)

Comment: I apologize because I don't believe my original question was detailed enough. I'm designing this for iPhone and iPad. I need the bottom half of this tableview controller to be taken up by the collection view. The collection view will display the photos returned to me by Foursquare. The collection view can scroll horizontally. I want the collection view to look like a grid/photo gallery. So the number of rows would need to adjust based on the size of the device and size of the collection view while also retaining the appropriate amount of spacing between the cells and rows based on device size.

Comment: your item sizing function looks right to me, are you sure the function is called ?

Comment: It seems to be. I think my problem might by just throwing the container view on top of the tableview controller. I'm going to try using a container view for it and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set your min spacing as required(Check putting it to 0 0 first), also add height and width of the cell as following:-

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{

        return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width/5, collectionView.frame.size.height/3)

}
```

Also check your constraints of imageView to be 0,0,0,0 (top,bottom,leading,trailing).

**Note**:- if you put some value in min spacing then you have to reduce it from size of the cell for example if you take 2 as min spacing for cell then reduce it from width (collectionView.frame.size.width/5 - 2) and suppose you took 3 for min spacing for lines then reduce it from height (collectionView.frame.size.height/5 - 3). Basically "for cells" is spacing between cells in a row horizontally and "for lines" is spacing between cells in a column vertically.